# extending <VirtualHost _default_:443> defined in conf.d/ssl.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I have some global directories, aliases and rewrite rules in my httpd.conf. They aplly to both 80 and 443.

Now I want to add an http proxy on port 3128. I don't want it to be affected by existing directives, so I try to surround them with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work for 443, because there's already a VirtualHost defined in `conf.d/ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

How to correctly share my custom directives so they apply to 80 and 443 and not 3128 with minimal editing?

Comment: Did you tried * instead of _default_ ? Can you post more informations (Alias & rewrites) ?

Comment: @Froggiz I did.

Comment: You can try to remove the ServerName & Alias from _default_:443 configuration. Can you post more informations (Alias & rewrites & SSL) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put theses rewrites and alias in the global configuration.

Instead, create a file containing this, and include it in you Vhosts 80 and 443 but not 3128.